# Servlet request.getParameter() returning null

Tags: java, jsp

I'm having a problem with JSP + Java.

When I put the line `@MultiPartConfig` in my `Servlet_1` and the attribute `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in my form that calls the `Servlet_1`, the method `request.getParameter("data")` returns `null`.

Why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `Collection<Part> parts = request.getParts();` method to read [request](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/Part.html) params.